# Disable / enable secondary HDD with OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, macbook, power

I have installed a second HDD in my MacBook Pro, by replacing the CD drive. I can "Eject" the drive and then it stops spinning and thus using extra power. However, if I put the computer to sleep and wake it up again the drive does no show up (can't "eject" again) but it is spinning.

How can I re-insert / re-mount the internal drive after ejecting? Is there a better way to manage the drive / power?

**Update**

I realized I can use "Disk Utility" to remount the drive, and then I can use finder to eject the drive again (and make it power down). But is there:

- A way I can use a script to unmount / eject the drive?
- A way to have (whatever) scripts automatically run on resume from sleep?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried mounting in Disk Utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an applescript along the lines of

```
do shell script "diskutil mount /dev/disk1s2"
do shell script "diskutil eject /dev/disk1s2"
```

replacing disk1s2 with the one you're working with... I'm terrible at terminal commands and scripting so there's probably a better way to get the disk in question. Hopefully someone else also answers and fixes that.

Then you can attach the script to [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) or [Power Manager](http://www.dssw.co.uk/index.html) to execute on sleep. The former requires some command line scripting and what not. I don't know of any way that doesn't require third party software.